# Excel not opening

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an issue with Microsoft Excel: When I click on the programme to open it, it won't open. Sometimes the loading screen or the "would you like to start in safe mode?" error message pops up very briefly (literally just a millisecond - I was able to identify the message by looking in event viewer).

Other office applications worked and excel used to work as a 32-bit application. Excel does run with 64 bit office installed, however the user has a sage add-in that won't work in 64 bit excel, 
I have tried reinstalling office, also a "proper uninstall" (manually removing office from programme files and programme data after running the uninstaller then cleaning the registry).I've tried an "online repair" and also running it in safe mode and as an administrator in safe mode - these led to the same results.

Restarting the users PC allows me to open excel for a short amount of time, however after about 5-10 minutes the issue reoccurs. I found this out after running a windows update to check to see if that was the issue.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

You should try launching Excel with Command Prompt or PowerShell in safe mode. If you have the standard installation of Office the following commands should work for you:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
.\excel.exe /safe
```

You do not need to run the commands above in an elevated Command Prompt or PowerShell session. Check Microsoft's [Command-line switches for Microsoft Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6) documentation for more information about command line switches.